# Funny Division in C and Arduino

Tags: c#, c, arduino, division

TL;DR
Why does

```
   printf("%d\n", 042/10  );
```

return 3 and not 4?

Hey so i actually i actually had this doubt while i was in the Arduino IDE, but then just to verify I did try in another C compiler. The code in Question is here:

```
Serial.println(42/10);
```

This works fine, displays 4. The is the funny bit

```
Serial.println(042/10);
```

This return 3.

This seems very fundamental but I couldn't find a suitable post answering this. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The leading zero means it’s octal.  042 is equal to 34 in decimal.  And 34/10 is indeed 3 using int math.

Comment: Oh man, thanks.  I recognize your handle. Thanks for all your posts!

Answer (score 5):

The `042` from `printf("%d\n", 042/10  );` is interpreted as an octal value:

*042 (oct) = 34 (dec)*

so your division is actually: `(int)34/10` = 3

Answer (score -3):

`Serial.println(042/010);` will output `4`

Stems from the earliest days of C, when octal numbers were at least a bit more common than nowadays (?). Once it's defined, you can't ever change it.

Comment: Is this even an answer? At least explain that the leading zero means "octal"...

Comment: _when octal numbers were at least a bit more common than nowadays_  You haven't played much Arduino right?

Comment: @DavidRanieri, you use octal while coding for Arduino?

Comment: @Juraj less than hexadecimal but more than decimal

Comment: @ David Ranieri: I use C since I wanted to get rid of FORTRAN. And always preferred the hex notation for bit patterns, since the modern times when bytes consist of 8 bits. Now in the new millenium and with arduino, I never used octal myself. And I hoped *mentioning* is enough as a hint where to search.

Comment: @datafiddler yeah, for me it was enough (I didn't downvote), it is a matter of taste but they are still used a lot, especially for flags and file permissions

Comment: You're right about the unix-style file permissions. (Again, I don't care about those on Arduino)

Comment: However, for me, old and with little memory :) they have a huge utility, I can easily remember this sequence (powers of 2) since they are pairs skipping the six and eights `00001, 00002, 00004, 00010, 00020, 00040, 00100, 00200, 00400, 01000, 02000, 04000, ...` without a calculator nor using ugly tricks like `1U << 1, 1U << 2, 1U << 3 ...`

Comment: My problem with this answer is that it makes it seem that writing `042/010` is doing `42/10` like the user wants. But it actually does `34/8` which is not clear here.